# How to get redirect link PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl, hyperlink

i'm trying to get redirect link using curl.

```
$url = 'link.com'
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
curl_close($ch);
$r= !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : '';
echo $r;
```

for a lot of URL it's work, but for this link

```
https://layarkaca21.tv/movie/play.php?movie=orphan-2009&size=360&server=0
```

i got redirected to

```
https://layarkaca21.tv/movie/z.mp4
```

but, if i paste in url browser, it's redirect me to

```
https://r1---sn-npo7zn7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=531d3cf85231b408&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=36.71.238.97&ipbits=32&expire=1465755678&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,requiressl,source&signature=0B2A93D2B19BE8E469655290263803331DADF8CE.237145461C178D6C26871FB461FF43427DD901C1&key=cms1&pl=22&begin=0&cache=HIT&redirect_counter=1&req_id=d0b9e16098efa3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-npo7zn7k&ms=nxu&mt=1465741245&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjAxKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE
```

i want to get that link using CURL, is that possible?
thx :)

Comment: You have CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to false, meaning it won't follow the redirects. Set that to true.

Comment: it doesn't work. i tested it :(

Comment: [The request follows multiple redirects](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/jXd7o). Your code just gets the first one.